# Invoke in C# not executing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke

I am learning how to make games in unity and following brackeys tutorial but I am having trouble my invoke is not triggering restart. Please Help

```
using UnityEngine;
using  UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class Gamemanager : MonoBehaviour
{
bool gameHasEnded = false;
public float restartDelay = 1f;

public void EndGame()
{
    if (gameHasEnded == false)
    {
        gameHasEnded = true;
        Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
        Invoke("Restart()", restartDelay);
    }


void Restart()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}}
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Invoke` method in a wrong manner. You should only supply method's name.

```
Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
```

Comment: I suggest to use the `nameof` method to not have a magic string. ```Invoke(nameof(Restart), restarDelay);```